# Add square beside text form

Tags: html, css

I want to place a square beside Yes and beside No text as:

[image]

I try:

```css
.yesNoSquare {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="yesNoSquare" /> YES
  <span class="yesNoSquare" /> NO
</div>
```

But it is adding the label inside square, how can I do my expected result?

Comment: you need to correctly write HTML by opening and closing your span elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Hope it helps.

```css
.yesNoSquare {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
    <div>
      <span class="yesNoSquare"></span>
      <span> YES</span>
      <span class="yesNoSquare"></span>
      <span> NO</span>
    </div>
```